# Converting YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm for Google Calendar

Tags: php

I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to convert the current timestamp to one that works as a parameter for google calendar. I'm using PHP.

Right now the format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm. The date I'm trying to convert is:

2020-03-11 10:00:00

So far I've tried using gmdate and passing in the current date with strtotime but I can't figure out how to make it the right format.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That isn't the complete date format, right?

Comment: From your question it is really not obvious which date format you are starting from and which date format you want to get to. But basically the DateTime class in PHP should do all this for you

Answer (score 0):

you can do in php like:

```
date('your needed format here', strtotime($yourtime))
```

check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for format detail. that will give you the needed string.
`date()` will convert unix time format in given format, the `strtotime()` makes unix time out of almost any time format string, it will detect the format automatically.